# What keys did I press to cause ">>" to appear in the left margin?

Tags: vim, vi

What Vim command did I invoke to cause a top-to-bottom gray bar with the character sequence ">>" in the current line's left margin to appear? (See screenshot below)

[image: http://imgur.com/8l9s4]

This happens every once and a while but I'm usually typing too quickly to realize what clumsy key combo caused it.

Comment: To those voting to close:  falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: off topic: You can tell what the color theme is using, I found very good

Comment: @user107745 [256-jungle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2240)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably a signs column. Signs API is very dumb, so there aren't lots of plugins using it, and it is even worse that `verbose sign list` won't show you place where particular sign is defined. On my system somebody has defined sign named `es_sign` that has text `>>` and highlighting `Error` (yes, just like on your image) and `grep -rw es_sign /usr/share/vim` shows that it was defined by `errsign` plugin. According to this plugin help, to get this sign placed you should type `\es`. Note that you may actually want to grep not just `/usr/share/vim`, but `~/.vim`, `~/vim-addons` or `/path/to/directory/with/vim/plugins` as well.

// By the way, thanks that you made me find another package that was left out unhandled by package manager after I reinstalled the system.

Comment: `>>` have recently appeared on my system. From what I can gather, it appeared when I tried to use `eclim` with gvim. `eclim` requires to install some files in `~/.vim/` so it is probably in one of thoses files for me.

Comment: You are correct, signs (used by rubysnippets) is responsible for this behavior. This is mentioned in the release notes for version 0.0.8 of [rubysnippets](http://goo.gl/eKtxt). Apparently I typed `is` to add the sign, and I can type `rs` to remove it. Much thanks, @ZyX.